# How to match an element of an array with element of JSON array in python

Tags: python, json

I have an problem with topic mentioned in header. I have an "exm" that element of it should be matched with elements of an another array called "JSON_array". Here is the arrays:

```
exm= ["ACA", "TTG", "CCG" ...]

JSON_array = {
   'ATA':'I', 
   'TTG':'M', 
   'ATT':'O'
}
```

For example, at here, elemnet "TTG" in "exm" matches with element 'TTG' in "JSON_array" and I want to print 'M' (which is matching of 'TTG' in "JSON_arraay") to the screen. How can i do that?

Comment: I'm assuming your `JSON_array` (actually an object, rather than array, to use the JS terminology) is already in the form of a Python dictionary? In which case this is a very straightforward problem - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
exm= ["ACA", "TTG", "CCG"]

JSON = {
   'ATA':'I', 
   'TTG':'M', 
   'ATT':'O'
}

for element in exm:
  print(JSON.get(element, 'No such element'))
```

By the way, your JSON object is not an `array`. It is `dictionary`, because arrays are jusr indexed set of elements, while dictionaries are key-value pairs.

Comment: Some call dictionaries "associative arrays"

Comment: @Caleth, agree, also `map` can be used. Just highlighted that in this context name `JSON_array` was a definate misuse.

Answer (score -2):

```
exm= ["ACA", "TTG", "CCG"]
JSON_array = {
'ATA':'I', 
'TTG':'M', 
'ATT':'O'
}

key = [val for val in JSON_array]

try:
    for val in exm:
        if val in key:
            print (JSON_array[val])
        else:
            pass
except:
    pass
```

Comment: what's the `try ... except: pass` here for? and why not `JSON_array.keys()`?

Comment: Just to make sure your program does not stop.

Comment: Just carrying on, regardless of errors, is the *worst* way to handle exceptions

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.